How to pass a value from dialog component to its parent page?
The plus button shows a dialog(component) there a new record can be added.
What is the best way to pass the added ID of the new record back to the first page?
After some search I found that there are Two ways
1- Using app state variable, which I think it's not practical.
2- Using navigation which, is not this approach cases overhead?
I want to know is there another way or which way is the best.?
Any detail step by step explanation will be helpful...
First page

Dialog (Component)


Why, using state variable is not practical?

@Aks Its visible all across the app, if I use that I might have hundreds of app state variables, as i have more than one dialog

use Navigator.pop( result:'foo');
final result= await Navigator.pop( result:'foo');

otherwise you should use statemangment class like Provider or Getx
    class Result extends ChangeNotifier{
    String result;
    void setResultValue(String result){
    this.result=result;
    notifylistner();  /// if needed
 }
    }

call this funcation
setResultValue('foo');

